# MSBuild Unhandled Exception: The FileName property should not be a directory unless UseShellExecute is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker

**Versions**

- dotnet core sdk: 2.1.403
- docker: 18.09.7
- Linux Kernel: 5.0.0-27
- Ubuntu: 18.04.3

**Problem**

I am running a ASP.NET Core project in docker. When I docker-compose up, I get the following:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeFailedToLaunchException: The FileName property should not be a directory unless UseShellExecute is set. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The FileName property should not be a directory unless UseShellExecute is set.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderOutOfProcBase.LaunchNode(String msbuildLocation, String commandLineArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.BuildProject(String projectFile, String[] targets, String toolsVersion, Dictionary`2 globalProperties, Dictionary`2 restoreProperties, ILogger[] loggers, LoggerVerbosity verbosity, DistributedLoggerRecord[] distributedLoggerRecords, Int32 cpuCount, Boolean enableNodeReuse, TextWriter preprocessWriter, Boolean detailedSummary, ISet`1 warningsAsErrors, ISet`1 warningsAsMessages, Boolean enableRestore, ProfilerLogger profilerLogger, Boolean enableProfiler)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Execute(String[] commandLine)
   at Microsoft.Build.CommandLine.MSBuildApp.Main(String[] args)
```

The error seems to occur when it hits the `dotnet restore` line in the dockerfile.

After checking for permissions, it seems that docker has read/write permissions to all the files/folders directly involved

There were some updates this morning that others on this post have said they also had. Whether they were the same updates is unknown. But there were a couple updates. [Here is my update log from the morning that this all started happening](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/820229/history.log).

My Dockerfile is like so:

```sh
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.403-sdk as dotnet

WORKDIR /vsdbg

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

WORKDIR /ProjA

# Install TRX -> JUnit log file converter
# https://github.com/gfoidl/trx2junit
RUN dotnet tool install -g trx2junit
RUN export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

COPY ProjA.sln .
COPY ProjA/ProjA.csproj ./ProjA/
COPY ProjA.Tests/ProjA.Tests.csproj ./ProjA.Tests/
COPY ProjB/ProjB.csproj ./ProjB/
COPY ProjC/ProjC.csproj ./ProjC/

RUN mkdir ProjA.Tests/tmp

RUN dotnet restore # ******* Error seems to happen here...

COPY . .

WORKDIR /ProjA/ProjA/

CMD ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Comment: Is there a directory present with the same name you want to compose the container to?

Comment: What do you mean by compose the container to? Like store the container image? I wouldn't know what the name would be

Comment: Do you mean that name of the container? like in `docker-compose up <name-of-container>`?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I have purged docker and reinstalled an older version; "sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic"
Surprisingly, it installed again 19.03.2 and the problem persists.

Comment: And yesterday, I didn't have any problem with docker-compose up, it started today. If I run only the faulty project with docker (not with docker-compose up) it works.

Comment: This was a bug in ubuntu family linux kernels.  It was fixed in the 5.0.0-31.33 release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and **downgrading** the linux kernel **from 5.0.0-27-generic to 5.0.0.-25-generic** fixed it.

A simple way to downgrade the linux kernel is to use the package **Uku**, which license costs 12$.

The **free alternative** is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry).

Another possibility is to **increase the GRUB Timeout** and choose the desired kernel version in the boot menu on every system start manually, which is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version).

Comment: This worked! Specifically, I used Ukuu to remove the new unwanted kernel after I booted into the old version. See [Rollback the changes/Downgrade Linux Kernel](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/).

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick thanks for sharing the link, Ukuu makes up- and downgrading the kernel a lot easier. Unfortunately you have to pay 12$ for a license.

Comment: I used it free. Just download it and it should work

Comment: I did see discussion about some newer kernels being liscenced, but the latest I could see was 5.2.13 which worked for me

Comment: This bug has now been fixed in the ubuntu 5.0.0-31.33 kernel

Answer (score 12):

We run Ubuntu 18.04 on Azure as our Docker hosts. Azure recently pushed out kernel version 5.0.0-1018, which caused the issue in our Linux containers. Downgrading to kernel version 4.18.0-1025 fixed it for us.

Comment: In my case, downgrading from kernel 5.0.0-27-generic to kernel 5.0.0-25-generic fixed the issue. That's on Ubuntu 19.04, running bare metal.

Comment: There's a bug report over at Ubuntu Launchpad:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1843018 . You can upvote the bug report by clicking the "This bug affects me too" link just below the issue title.

Comment: Thanks Frederik! You've done some great sleuthing. I've upvoted the issue.

Comment: How did you downgrade the linux kernel?

Answer (score 3):

The **simplest solution** is for `.Net Core 2.1 and 2.2` is using lower Ubuntu version.

```
on: [push]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag yourtagname:$(date +%s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. Update Ubuntu kernel to last version (5.0.0-27-generic) solve the problem.

Comment: Some people on here (@Frederik Carlier) have said they downgraded from there though. I'll try doing this but it seems to be another issue

Comment: We had [issues](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3309) with [5.0.0-27](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1843018) and downgraded to -23 which was the kernel for the latest successful build.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today, with docker files that were working fine for months.
There were some repos that worked, but others simply didn't. Without ANY changes. Docker files failed to run and got this same error "MSBuild Unhandled Exception: The FileName property should not be a directory unless UseShellExecute is set".
I was originally using docker 18.09.7 and upgraded to 19.3.2, but that didn't help.

I was running Ubuntu 18.04.3 and had noticed some updates installing in the morning.
This is a simple build system, with very little installed (VS Code, Gitkraken, docker, docker-compose)

Since some of my builds were failing and I couldn't find a culprit, I reinstalled
and downgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.2 and reinstalled the few things I need to build. And everything was working again. 
I suspect the updates in the morning broke things. Unfortunately I didn't keep the upgrade log :-(

Comment: I had the updates as well that morning that I posted this

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem since yesterday, but the problem stems from ubuntun, because I created and worked without problems from kali linux, but I continued to receive errors despite my attempts at 18.04 and 19.04.

**Docker version**

```
Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:29:11 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
COPY . project/
WORKDIR /project
run dotnet restore dotnet.sln 

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /Project/
RUN dotnet publish dotnet.sln -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
COPY . Project/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8003

FROM runtime AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnet.dll"]
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the ubuntu kernel 5.0.0-27-generic, but the problem is solved when I do the download.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been confirmed on Ubuntu:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1843018

Relevant .net Core issue: 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40850

Answer (score 0):

Solutions

apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa

 apt-get update

 apt-get install ukuu

 ukuu --install-latest

 reboot

 uname -sr

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 9.04. I made the downgrade to `linux-generic=5.0.0.13.14` and it's working now!

Just run the following command :

`sudo apt install linux-image-generic=5.0.0.13.14 linux-headers-generic=5.0.0.13.14 linux-generic=5.0.0.13.14`

Then restart using "Ubuntu Advanced options" and then choose the `linux-generic_5.0.0.13.14`opton.